# What exactly is a nonkit personal computer?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Upgrading and Repairing PCs, 21st Edition by Scott Mueller (2013)](http://www.quepublishing.com/store/upgrading-and-repairing-pcs-9780789750006)

Example:

> 1973: The Micral is the earliest commercial, **nonkit personal computer** based on a microprocessor, the Intel 8008.

What exactly are these nonkit personal computers and how are they different from the regular ones?

Comment: A computer not built from a kit?

Comment: Well, you tell me.

Comment: A computer not built from a kit.

Comment: And what does that mean? What kind of kit?

Comment: A kit of computer parts.  And not necessarily all the parts you needed.  Almost certainly did not include a case, or any sort of display or keyboard.

Comment: Heathkit was the name for electronic DIY kits.

Comment: http://www.wd8afb.com/heath.html

Comment: @Cascabel - Actually, no.  Reading that again makes me notice that "non-kit" was specified.  A "kit" implies at least a subset of the necessary parts in a single package from a single source, with instructions.  "Non-kit" implies that you buy the individual parts from various sources and assemble them yourself, with no instructions.  Back in 1974 I had about 1/3 of a non-kit computer put together, but never got much farther.  (I still have parts of it out in the garage.)  Many other hobbyists were more persistent and finished their systems.

Comment: @HotLicks But they are calling this Micral a non-kit, and it looks like a commercially fabricated unit. Comes in a case and everything...color me confused.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yeah, it's confusing.  I wrote an "answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "nonkit personal computer" appears to imply a computer that was, for its time, "complete" as it came "out of the box".  Though it may have lacked what we might now consider "essential" pieces, such as a keyboard, it was presumably in one piece, fully assembled.

At that time you could buy, from various sources, "kits" of various degrees of completeness, including electronic parts, boards to assemble them on, maybe a case, maybe a power supply.  Plus instructions, of one form or another.  The [Altair 8800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800), introduced in 1974, was one of the most successful computers in this category, and was the machine on which Gates and Allen first ran their BASIC interpreter which got Microsoft started.

However, there were earlier (and more primitive) kit computers.  I don't recall any specifically, but likely Heath, the largest maker of electronic kits at that time, had several, ca 1973.  These would have been quite a bit more limited, in terms of function and performance, than the Intel 8080-based Altair.

A little earlier (starting maybe 1970) there were many hobbyists who put their own systems together from individual parts, first building "CPUs" from scratch out of individual integrated circuits, then using the early Intel single-chip processors -- the 4004 and 8008 -- as the basis of the design.  These were technically "nonkit", I suppose, but certainly not in the same sense as the Micral unit referenced by the OP.  (They would have been referred to as "scratch-built" in the jargon of the era.)

Comment: @Cascabel -- What do you mean "don't"?  I already did.  But looking it up, I'm reminded that the Z-80 was a sort of clone (released in 1976) of the Intel 8080, cheaper and "souped up" in some regards.  Not terribly relevant to the above question, but certainly a big part of the history of the era.

Comment: Yeah, when I remembered it came out in 76, I deleted the comment. I only go back to the 8080A, myself.

Comment: Here is Wikipedia's description of an early kit, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COSMAC_ELF, that I built.  It was a kit because you had to assemble it yourself, though the design and parts list were all worked out in a *Popular Electronics* article.  Places that sold such parts to hobbyists advertised in the back of the magazine.